# Unmapped Columns Still Included in FindByEmailAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using .NET core 3.1 and I have the following class defined:

```c#
public class AspNetUsers : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] public override bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] public override bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] public override string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] public override string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] public override string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
}
```

I then try to use the following (stubbed up, not yet handling roles) login endpoint:

```c#
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Account/Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(AspNetUsersViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    var validated = true;
    var message = "Invalid username or password.";
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password) == false)
        {
            validated = false;
        }

        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("UserRole", "Admin"));
        }
        else if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            message = "You are locked out.";
            validated = false;
        }
        if (!validated)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("message", "Invalid username or password.");
            return View(message);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

The issue that I'm running into is that when I hit the endpoint, I get a 500 response with the following exception message when it tries to run `FindByEmailAsync`:

> MySqlException: Unknown column 'a.ConcurrencyStamp' in 'field list'

I'm not exactly sure why I'm getting the exception because I would expect that by adding the `NotMapped` attribute to the property it would not be included in the request to the database.

What exactly am I missing?

**update**

Here is what the ConfigureServices in Startup.cs looks like:

```c#
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddIdentity<AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

    // configure the session
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    });

    // configure the identity options
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

        // lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;

        // user settings
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    });

    // configure the cookie options
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

    // configure the auth controller
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Authorized", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthController()));
    });
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, LoggedIn>();
}
```

Comment: Hi @David,can you share your `startup`?

Comment: Does your startup like this  `services.AddIdentity<AspNetUsers,IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultUI();`

Comment: @Yinqiu I've updated my post to include the startup, but yes it does have those chained methods.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work as you intend; my suspicion is that though your class overrides Microsoft's class and adds those NotMapped props, the instance will be treated as an `IdentityUser` by UserManager, which is expecting those props to be in the db. By corollorary, would you expect to be able to mark Email prop as NotMapped, not provide a db column for it, and expect FindByEmailAsync to find the user?

Comment: Hi @David,you can check your db to see whether the column exists.

Comment: @Yinqiu just pulled up PHP my admin and confirmed that the column does not exist.

Comment: @Yinqiu to confirm, the column does not exist by design. That is why I am adding the `[NotMapped]` attribute to the columns that do not exist in my database.

Comment: Hi @David,You should re-migrate and add these columns to the database. In general, your columns should exist in the database.

Comment: @Yinqiu the whole point was that I didn't want unused columns in my database. Is it not possible to modify the identity schema without having to fully rewrite the user manager?

Comment: @David,Since the default IdentityUer contains these columns, if your custom User does not contain these columns, an error will be raised.

Comment: You may need to modify the default method in identity.